# java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, prepared-statement

I am having two problems:

1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array

this I am getting when trying to convert List to JSON. Also plz tell me how to handle null array to json.

2) When I run the query on database it is fetching me 5 results.  When I debug the OperatorDetailsDao.java I get rs.next() to run only once. And another problem is that I get null result in operatorList though it is array of operators.

Please help me to sort out the problem, stuck for two days.

**Controller Class**

```
public class SearchController extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            response.setContentType("application/json");
            try {
                String term = request.getParameter("terms");
                System.out.println("Data from ajax call " + term);

                OperatorDetialsDao details = new OperatorDetialsDao();
                List<OperatorDetailsBean> operatorList = details.getOperators(term);
                            System.out.println("Operator List " + operatorList); 
                JsonElement element = new Gson().toJsonTree(operatorList);
                            System.out.println(element);
                            JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
                            response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
                            response.getWriter().flush();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

             doPost(request, response);
    }

}
```

OperatorDetailsDao -> getOperators()

```
public List<OperatorDetailsBean> getOperators(String name) {
          PreparedStatement ps = null;
          List<OperatorDetailsBean> operatorList = new ArrayList();
          operatorList = null;
          name = name.toUpperCase();
          String data;
          try {
              ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM operator_details_m  WHERE upper(name) LIKE ?");
              ps.setString(1, name + '%');
              ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

              while (rs.next()) {
                  uname = rs.getString("NAME");
                  token = rs.getString("TOKEN_NO");
                  OperatorDetailsBean op = new OperatorDetailsBean();
                  op.setName(uname);
                  op.setTokenNo(token);
                  operatorList.add(op);
              }

          } catch (Exception e) {
              //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
          return operatorList;
}
```

OperatorDetailsBean is a bean class with getter and setters.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a snippet of the JSON contents? As far as the data base loop is concerned it seems like you are encountering aNull pinter exception since you have set operatorList to null after initializing it in the line above -  but you are gulping it within the catch(Exception e) {}. You would want to simply remove the initialization statement that says operatorList = null

Comment: First of all, your code formatting isn't helping. Other than that, try posting your JSON string. If it starts with a '[' then it's an array, if it starts with a '{' its an object.

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande, I want to create a JSON for using in ajax, I have written code for creation of json in the controller file. But there operatorList  is returning null so I am unable to provide the json snippet. The arrayList (operatorList) contains  array of operators having fields "name" and "token" both being String.

Comment: In OperatorDetailsDao.getOperators() please remove the line `operatorList = null`. You would then be able to fetch the `operatorList` from the DB.

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande Thanks! It worked. But can u explain why it was an issue anyways I was re-initializing operatorList  inside the loop by adding new operators.

Comment: Please refer to my answer. I am clearly annotating the code flow that would result in the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that both the problems are related to the incorrect initialization of the `operatorList` within the `OperatorDetailsDao.getOperators()` method. Below is an annotated explanation of the problem:

```
public List<OperatorDetailsBean> getOperators(String name) {
          PreparedStatement ps = null;
          List<OperatorDetailsBean> operatorList = new ArrayList();
          //Prahaladd - Setting this to null will cause operatorList to be null.
         // This is not being re-initalized anywhere else
          operatorList = null; 
          name = name.toUpperCase();
          String data;
          try {
              ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM operator_details_m  WHERE upper(name) LIKE ?");
              ps.setString(1, name + '%');
              ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

              while (rs.next()) {
                  uname = rs.getString("NAME");
                  token = rs.getString("TOKEN_NO");
                  OperatorDetailsBean op = new OperatorDetailsBean();
                  op.setName(uname);
                  op.setTokenNo(token);
                  operatorList.add(op); //Prahaladd - definitely a NullPointerException
              }

          } catch (Exception e) {
              //Prahaladd - Oops!! NPE thrown above was gulped.
              //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
          return operatorList; //returned operatorList is null. Will impact gson library processing
}
```

When this method is now called within the Controller :

```
 //Prahaladd - operatorList returned would be null
 List<OperatorDetailsBean> operatorList = details.getOperators(term);
                                System.out.println("Operator List " + operatorList); 
//Prahaladd - GSON processes this null value.
JsonElement element = new Gson().toJsonTree(operatorList);

 System.out.println(element);
 //Prahaladd - this will fail since we are trying to process a non-array
 // as a JSON array.
 JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
```

Removing the offending line `operatorList = null` will ensure that a valid **empty** array list and **not** a **null** value would be returned and would be correctly processed by GSON.

On a side note - there was an [issue logged](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/14) in the GSON library where it failes to handle NULL arrays and as per the comments this has been fixed.

Comment: @DevendraSingh Please mark my response as an answer if your problem has been resolved due to it :)